# Spring Data JPA findOne() change to Optional how to use this?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm learning `SpringBoot2.0` with `Java8`.

And I followed some blog-making tutorial example.

The tutorial source code is:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
public String edit(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("categoryDto", categoryService.findOne(id));
  return "category/edit";
}
```

But this code is throwing this error:

> categoryService.findOne(id)

I'm thinking about changing the JPA `findOne()` method to `Optional< S >`

How to solve that?

More info:

This is the categoryService method:

```
public Category findOne(Long id) {
  return categoryRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

Comment: 1. can you put the link to the blog u r following or can you show the full code. How is categoryService declaredß 2. What is the exception you are getting

Answer (score 257, accepted):

From at least, the `2.0` version, `Spring-Data-Jpa` modified `findOne()`.
Now, `findOne()` has neither the same signature nor the same behavior.
Previously, it was defined in the `CrudRepository` interface as:

```
T findOne(ID primaryKey);
```

Now, the single `findOne()` method that you will find in `CrudRepository` is the one defined in the `QueryByExampleExecutor` interface as:

```
<S extends T> Optional<S> findOne(Example<S> example);
```

That is implemented finally by `SimpleJpaRepository`, the default implementation of the `CrudRepository` interface.
This method is a query by example search and you don't want that as a replacement.

In fact, the method with the same behavior is still there in the new API, but the method name has changed.
It was renamed from `findOne()` to `findById()` in the [`CrudRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) interface :

```
Optional<T> findById(ID id);
```

Now it returns an `Optional`, which is not so bad to prevent `NullPointerException`.

**So, the actual method to invoke is now `Optional<T> findById(ID id)`.**

How to use that?
Learning [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) usage.
Here's important information about its specification:

> A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a
> value is present, isPresent() will return true and get() will return
> the value.
>
> Additional methods that depend on the presence or absence of a
> contained value are provided, such as orElse() (return a default value
> if value not present) and ifPresent() (execute a block of code if the
> value is present).

---

**Some hints on how to use `Optional` with `Optional<T> findById(ID id)`.**

Generally, as you look for an entity by id, you want to return it or make a particular processing if that is not retrieved.

Here are three classical usage examples.

1. Suppose that if the entity is found you want to get it otherwise you want to get a default value.

You could write :

```
Foo foo = repository.findById(id)
                    .orElse(new Foo());
```

or  get a `null` default value if it makes sense (same behavior as before the API change) :

```
Foo foo = repository.findById(id)
                    .orElse(null);
```

2. Suppose that if the entity is found you want to return it, else you want to throw an exception.

You could write :

```
return repository.findById(id)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(id));
```

3. Suppose you want to apply a different  processing according to if the entity is found or not (without necessarily throwing an exception).

You could write :

```
Optional<Foo> fooOptional = fooRepository.findById(id);
if (fooOptional.isPresent()) {
    Foo foo = fooOptional.get();
    // processing with foo ...
} else {
    // alternative processing....
}
```

Comment: thx david :) NotFoundEntity is extends RuntimeException { super("could not found " + id ); like this?

Comment: You are welcome. It is a "invented" exception. It can extend `Exception` or `RuntimeException` according to your need. But as said it is just an example :)

Comment: The first part is wrong: the method has not been moved to `QueryByExampleExecutor` it simply has been renamed to `findById(…)` returning an `Optional`. Also, always `….map(…)` on an `Optional`, never call `get()`.

Comment: @Oliver Gierke "In fact, the method with the same behavior is still there in the new API but the method name has changed" I little reworded but I think that that is right and that is the most important information.

Comment: thnx davidxxx. You save me

Comment: @davidxxx, what if I don't want to findById(...) but instead find by some other field/criteria e.g. name or something else?

Comment: @Artanis Zeratul  In this case you don't want to use `findById()` but using FindOne(Example), findAll(Example) or declare a query method in your Repository interface that allows Spring Data to create the query for you (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods). If the criteria of search varies criteria and specification are probably the more adapted ways.

Comment: I can add that this is a change made since version Spring 2.0 M3 (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-944)

Comment: Maybe EntityNotFoundException rather than NotFoundEntity is better.

Comment: @zhouji  Agreed and updated. Besides it is defined in the `javax.persistence` API as a `RuntimeException`. So makes really sense.

Comment: this was a hurdle for me also thanks for explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much david, that is wonderful explanation!

Answer (score 13):

The method has been renamed to `findById(…)` returning an `Optional` so that you have to handle absence yourself:

```
Optional<Foo> result = repository.findById(…);

result.ifPresent(it -> …); // do something with the value if present
result.map(it -> …); // map the value if present
Foo foo = result.orElse(null); // if you want to continue just like before
```

Comment: how think about return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundEntity(id));

Comment: this guy tells this is wrong: https://tuhrig.de/anti-pattern-dont-use-optionals-for-data-repositories/

Comment: Apparently someone's wrong – or at least not very nuanced – on the internet. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I think he is correct. For findById you have a specific identifier that came from the data store. It doesn't make sense to return an optional in this case

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, in the latest version of Spring Data, findOne returns an optional. If you want to retrieve the object from the Optional, you can simply use get() on the Optional. First of all though, a repository should return the optional to a service, which then handles the case in which the optional is empty. afterwards, the service should return the object to the controller.

Comment: Recommending to call `….get()` on an `Optional` is bad advice. `Optional` has dedicated methods to process the value.

Comment: indeed, for the purpose of handling the value, there are better methods, such as .orElse() or .orElseThrow(). But for simply retrieving the item without checking whether the repository call returned the desired object, .get() should just about do it

Comment: @OliverDrotbohm Optionals dont make sense when all you can do is throw a runtime exception and abort the code. In those instances I've seen developers inadvertently swallow bugs/exceptions/errors by using flatMap and ignoring the case that the object is gone. Where the code can't proceed without that object then get makes perfect sense and others will just mask the error. Its no different than checked exceptions vs unchecked. If theres nothing that can be done than a runtime/null pointer is fine so call .get(). If theres another course of action the user can take orElse makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

I always write a default method **"findByIdOrError"** in widely used CrudRepository repos/interfaces.

```
@Repository 
public interface RequestRepository extends CrudRepository<Request, Integer> {

    default Request findByIdOrError(Integer id) {
        return findById(id).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    } 
}
```

Comment: But this returns a Request object. How should I transform this into the Entity I am serching for (if its there)?

Answer (score 2):

`Optional` api provides methods for getting the values. You can check `isPresent()` for the presence of the value and then make a call to `get()` or you can make a call to `get()` chained with `orElse()` and provide a default value.

The last thing you can try doing is using `@Query()` over a custom method.

Comment: Recommending to call `….get()` on an `Optional` is bad advice. `Optional` has dedicated methods to process the value.

Answer (score 2):

The `findOne` method of the `CrudRepository interface` has been replaced by `findById` since version 2.0 of Spring Data Commons.
you replace  `findOne(id)`  by:

```
findById(id).orElse(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider an **`User`** entity and **`UserRepository`**. In service package code like below.

```
Optional<User> resultUser = UserRepository.findById(userId);  //return Optional

User createdUser = resultUser.get();  //return User
```

Now you can access all the User entity attributes using getter.

```
createdUser.getId(); 
createdUser.getName();
```

like that.