# findOne deosn't work, i change to findById but i got a problem in return type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i got an error in return type cp:Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional to Compte

this is in spring boot using eclipse

```
''Java 
@Service
@Transactional
public class BanqueMetierImpl implements IBanqueMetier{
@Autowired
 private COmpteRepository compteRepository;
 @Override
  public Compte ConsulterCompte(String codeCpte){
  Optional<Compte> cp=compteRepository.findById(codeCpte);
  if(cp==null)throw new RuntimeException("Compte Introuvable");
   return cp;
```

i'm trying to use findOne but doesn't work, so i use findById when did that i got an error in return type cp;

Comment: an Optional will not be null, you need to check **cp.isPresent()** if it true then data is found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data JPA findOne() change to Optional how to use this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316751/spring-data-jpa-findone-change-to-optional-how-to-use-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer Spring Data versions use `findById` instead of `findOne` and instead of returning `null` it now returns an `Optional`. It will never return `null` but rather an `Optional.empty()` instead.

Rewrite your code to properly use the `Optional`

```
@Override
public Compte ConsulterCompte(String codeCpte) {
  return compteRepository.findById(codeCpte)
           .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Compte Introuvable"));
}
```

Also you probably shouldn't be throwing a general `RuntimeException` but a more specific one.

Answer (score 1):

This code should works.

```
return cp.orElseThrow(()-> new RuntimeException("Compte Introuvable"));
```

I recommend you take a look at this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) to understand how Optional works.

Comment: Don't, using `isPresent` is generally a bad sign. Use `orElseThrow()` to remove the need for the `cp.isPresent`.