# JPA repository throwing null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa

I am fairly new to spring boot and jpa. I am doing small project for my learning purpose.

Entity class

```
package com.jranjanacademy.currencyexchangeservice.service;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class ExchangeService {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(name="currency_from")
    private String from;

    @Column(name="currency_to")
    private String to;

    private BigDecimal conversionMultiple;

    private int port;

    // == Constructors ==

    // == No arg Constructors ==
      public ExchangeService() {

      }

    // == Parametrised Constructors ==
    public ExchangeService(long id, String from, String to, BigDecimal conversionMultiple) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.conversionMultiple = conversionMultiple;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the from
     */
    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    /**
     * @param from the from to set
     */
    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    /**
     * @return the to
     */
    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    /**
     * @param to the to to set
     */
    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    /**
     * @return the conversionMultiple
     */
    public BigDecimal getConversionMultiple() {
        return conversionMultiple;
    }

    /**
     * @param conversionMultiple the conversionMultiple to set
     */
    public void setConversionMultiple(BigDecimal conversionMultiple) {
        this.conversionMultiple = conversionMultiple;
    }

    /**
     * @return the port
     */
    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    /**
     * @param port the port to set
     */
    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
package com.jranjanacademy.currencyexchangeservice.controller;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import com.jranjanacademy.currencyexchangeservice.service.ExchangeService;
    import com.jranjanacademy.currencyexchangeservice.service.ExchangeServiceRepository;

    @RestController
    public class ExchangeServiceController {

        @Autowired
        private Environment environment;

        @Autowired
        private ExchangeServiceRepository exchangeServiceRepository;

        @GetMapping("/currency-exchange/from/{from}/to/{to}")
        public ExchangeService retrieveExchangeValue(@PathVariable String from, @PathVariable String to){
            ExchangeService exchangeValue =
                    exchangeServiceRepository.findByFromAndTo(from, to);
        exchangeValue.setPort(
                    Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("local.server.port")));
        return exchangeValue;
        }
    }
```

JPARepository

```
package com.jranjanacademy.currencyexchangeservice.service;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ExchangeServiceRepository extends JpaRepository<ExchangeService, Long>{

    ExchangeService findByFromAndTo(String from, String to);
}
```

data.sql looks like below and I can see the table in h2 console

```
insert into exchange_service(id,currency_from,currency_to,conversion_multiple,port)
values(1001,'USD','INR',75,0);
insert into exchange_service(id,currency_from,currency_to,conversion_multiple,port)
values(1002,'AUD','INR',42,0);
insert into exchange_service(id,currency_from,currency_to,conversion_multiple,port)
values(1003,'EUR','INR',65,0);
insert into exchange_service(id,currency_from,currency_to,conversion_multiple,port)
values(1004,'POUND','INR',51,0);
```

I am getting below exception when I am trying to acceess the url "http://localhost:8000/currency-exchange/from/INR/to/USD"

```
2020-05-21 21:14:58.229 ERROR 9384 --- [nio-8000-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.jranjanacademy.currencyexchangeservice.controller.ExchangeServiceController.retrieveExchangeValue(ExchangeServiceController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
```

Application.properties

```
spring.application.name=currency-exchange-service
server.port=8000
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Any leads?

Comment: Two questions: Is the data populated in your table? Can you confirm this? Also, What does your application.properties look like?

Comment: Can you add the @Repository annotation to the repository interface any try?

Comment: yes, I can see the data in h2 console. application.properties looks like below.

spring.application.name=currency-exchange-service
server.port=8000
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

Comment: @TharakaDevinda I tried putting Repository annotation in the interface but still no joy. I see the same error.

Comment: Se ta break point in your controller and check what variables are *null* and tell us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay from the Question I could see 2 things

1. The Inserted Items are

```
id,  | currency_from | currency_to | conversion_multiple |port
1001 |    'USD'      |    'INR'    |     75.             |0
1002 |    'AUD'      |    'INR'    |     42              |0
1003 |    'EUR'      |    'INR'    |     65              |0
1004 |    'POUND'    |    'INR'    |     51              |0
```

2. The Request `http://localhost:8000/currency-exchange/from/INR/to/USD`

```
From : INR, TO : USD
```

So I suspect in the below line you must have got NULL value since `FROM :INR` to `TO: USD` is not present in the table

```java
ExchangeService exchangeValue = exchangeServiceRepository.findByFromAndTo(from, to);
```

So solution would be,

- Check if the `exchangeValue` is `null` before processing.

(or)

- Return  Employee as `Optional` data, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316751/spring-data-jpa-findone-change-to-optional-how-to-use-this) (Above sol is simpler this for better code quality)

Comment: yes, exchangeValue is null. But why it's comming as null? Thanks

Comment: `select * from exchange_service where currency_from = 'INR' and currency_to='USD';` will return empty that is why `exchangeValue` is null

Comment: Because as @Avi suggested, according to your URL `http://localhost:8000/currency-exchange/**from/INR**/to/USD` you don't have such entity in table which has `currency_from` with INR value.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the explanation. I was using wrong url. I should have used http://localhost:8000/currency-exchange/from/USD/to/INR.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you're not receiving an exception at the start of runtime. The `ExchangeServiceRepository` reference is null. You need to add the `@Repository` annotation to the type `ExchangeServiceRepository`. Spring is likely unable to autowire this Bean because it's not annotated as a Repository (DAO) which at it's core is a `@Component`.

```java
@Repository
public interface ExchangeServiceRepository extends JpaRepository<ExchangeService, Long>{

    ExchangeService findByFromAndTo(String from, String to);
}
```

I don't see your main class so make sure you call `@EnableJpaRepositories` so that Spring Boot can pickup your repositories.

Comment: I tried putting Repository annotation in the interface but still no joy. I see the same error

Comment: I also had the initial suspicion there. But seems its not the case with him. Since JpaRepository is there, is that really needed?

Comment: I am very positive that @Repository is not required becoz I am able to use defaut methods of JpaRepository but not sure what is happening when I am trying to use "ExchangeService findByFromAndTo(String from, String to);".

Comment: That is extremely odd. Have you called the annotation @EnableJpaRepositories in the application entry-point class?

Comment: @Json what do you mean by application entry-point class? Do you mean main class? If yes, I have tried adding EnableJpaRepositories annotation in the main class as well but still I see the same exception

Comment: Yes. Can you update the main post with your main class as well? Would be nice to see how you're managing configuration/auto-configuration.

Comment: You don't actually need to add `@Repository`, implementing `JpaRepository` the spring startup will take care of `autowiring`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
@Value("${local.server.port}")
int port;
```

instead of

```
environment.getProperty("local.server.port")
```

It seems that problem is there.
In order to refute or confirm this, simply delete the line with `exchangeValue.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("local.server.port")));`

Comment: I commented above line of code and now I am not getting any exception. But I do not see any output in the browser either. I logged the value of "exchangeValue" and found it to be null and this is the reason why I was getting null pointer exception coz I was trying to set port to null reference. Now I am not sure why am I getting null reference of exchangeValue.